# How to solve Quartz class not found error for quartz 1.8.5 jar in spring 4 Or how to create dynamic scheduler in spring 4?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to implement dynamic scheduler in spring mvc its done but @autowired problem are occurs means data not found by called method in scheduler method.
i am used quartz 1.8.5 dependency and spring 4. if i try to initialized bean then CronTriggerBean class not found..

CronTriggerExample.java-

public class CronTriggerExample {

```
public void schedulerMethod() throws SchedulerException{
    //JobDetail job = new JobDetail();
    //job.setName("dummyJobName");
    //job.setJobClass(HelloJob.class);      

    JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(EmailSchedularController.class)
            .withIdentity("dummyJobName", "group1").build();
       System.out.println("cron trigger method..");
    //CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger();
    //trigger.setName("dummyTriggerName");
    //trigger.setCronExpression("0/5 * * * * ?");

    String cronstr = "0 48 11 ? * *";
    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("dummyTriggerName", "group1")
            .withSchedule(
                    CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronstr))
            .build();

    //schedule it
    Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
    scheduler.start();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
}
```

///////////////////////
Job class =

class EmailSender implements Job{

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
            throws JobExecutionException {

        File excelFile = null;
        File pdfFile = null;
        try{

            List<ConsumptionReportBO> invoiceList= emailSender.listConsumptionInv();
            System.out.println("invoice list: "+invoiceList.get(0).getInvestorName());
                 for(ConsumptionReportBO consumption :invoiceList ){

                     int month = 0;
                     int year = 0;
                     Bill bill= report.generateExcel(month,year);

                     pdfFile= consumptionInv.generateConsPdf(month,year);
                     String pdfFileName = fileUtility.saveFile(pdfFile);
                     File[] fileArr = {pdfFile,bill.getFile()};

                     String oftkEmail = offtaker.getEmail();
                     String[] emailArray = oftkEmail.split(",");

                     String[] bcc = oftkEmail.split(",");

                     MasterData mData = new MasterData();
                     String mEmail = mData.getEmail();
                     String[] mEmailArr = MaxEmail.split(",");
                     emailUtility.sendMail(emailArray,mEmailArr,null,"Hi, this month invoice", "Invoice",  fileArr);

                 }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

}

this is work but EmailSenderController emailSender  = new EmailSenderController();

class contains @Autowired class there null pointer exception occur
i am also try initialize bean but there Class not found error occur code as..

```
 <bean id="sendEmailToAdmin" 
         class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" scope="singleton">

<bean id="cronTrigger"  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean"> 
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="sendEmailToAdmin`enter code here`" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 12 * * ?" /> 
    </bean>
```

Comment: NO there is no proper solution

Comment: show some code what you have done so far and your project structure.

Comment: i am edit my question with code please read..